# CodeIgniter: Multi-select input isn't able to select multiple values

Tags: forms, codeigniter

Ironically, form_multiselect() I created didn't work for me. Actually it was created but I couldn't select multiple options. I followed the instructions on the user guide but still not functioning like a multi-select although it looks like one. Any silly mistakes I've made?

**This is what the code looks like in web browser's inspect element feature:**

```
<select name="meal_type[]" id="meal_type_id" onfocus="calculateTotal();" onblur="calculateTotal();" onchange="calculateTotal();" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Breakfast_1000">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="Dinner_2500">Dinner</option>
    <option value="Lunch_2000">Lunch</option>
</select>
```

**This is what I coded in View:**

```
<div class="control-group">     
    <label for="meal_type" class="control-label">
        <i class="icon-glass"></i> Meal Type: 
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
    <?php
        $js = 'id="meal_type_id" onFocus="calculateTotal();" onBlur="calculateTotal();" onChange="calculateTotal();"';
        echo form_multiselect('meal_type[]', $mt_name, set_value('meal_type'), $js);
    ?>
    <?php echo form_error('meal_type'); ?>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function calculateTotal() {

    var room_type_id = document.getElementById('room_type_id').value;
    var room_type_cost = room_type_id.split("_");

    var meal_type_id = document.getElementById('meal_type_id').value;
    var meal_type_cost = meal_type_id.split("_");

    var ext_beds_id = document.getElementById('ext_beds_id').value;
    var ext_beds_cost = ext_beds_id.split("_");

    var reservation_duration = document.getElementById('reservation_duration').value;
    var total_payable = ( parseInt(room_type_cost[1]) + parseInt(meal_type_cost[1]) + parseInt(ext_beds_cost[1]) ) * parseInt(reservation_duration);
    document.getElementById('total_amount').value = total_payable;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your event handling function calculateTotal is conflicting with the multi selects default behavior.  Hard to tell though unless your post that code.

Comment: I tried creating form_multiselect() without $js variable but it didn't work either. Here's the JavaScript function: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5858882/

Comment: There must be something else going on. I pasted your rendered code into [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/yU9Zc/), and you can most definitely select multiples. Are you getting any javascript errors? (Check your browser console.) What do the other fields required by the function look like? If you console.log their values, are they getting what you expect them to get?

Comment: There is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @EmmyS I checked the console and it looks like normal: http://i.imgur.com/Yv5u8uJ.png